# Using the slick2d library, how do I get the value of 'delta' into the render() method?

Tags: java, slick2d

So I'm doing my first java assignment, which is to make a very basic game using slick2d.
[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elj5N.png)

Notice the little yellow bus on the left hand side.  I need this bus to be moving from left to right across the screen.  Rendering the bus as stationary is easy:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    bus.draw(0, 432);
}
```

But I need to use 'delta' to move it from left to right.  Now I know that the update method has delta in it:

```
public void update(Input input, int delta) throws SlickException {
}
```

but the render method does not.

**How can I get the value of delta into the render method?**

(Without changing the method signatures cause apparently that screws everything up when using slick2d)

Comment: Would you consider providing feedback whether answers regarding your posts are helpful or not? Others might find it relevant too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to save the delta value in an attribute of your class.
So on top of your class simply:

```
private int deltaValue;
```

and inside your update method:

```
public void update(Input input, int delta) throws SlickException {
    deltaValue = delta;
}
```

Then you can access your delta value inside your render method:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
  //  System.out.println(deltaValue);
}
```